# Data validation list doesn't auto populate with new row

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I'm at a loss with the data validation lists in my table. I am using the form field to enter new values into my table. Using this method the new row does apply to the table but not all of my data validation fills down. The data validation that does not use lists fills down while the data validation that uses lists does not. See the images below.

[image: First cell in row]
[image: Data validation not using list]
[image: Data validation using list]

However, if I insert a row anywhere in the table everything works as it should. See the pictures below.

[image: First cell in row]
[image: Data validation not using list]
[image: Data validation using list]

I could really use some help. Also, if someone can also tell me why the row banding isn't filling down as well would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are your questions? What columns/cells are you applying data validation rules to? What exactly are the specs of those data validation rules (show the details of the rules)?

Comment: Every cell in the row has a validation attached to it, I don't think there is an easy way to show the rules of each cell. I'm not sure how to make it more clear that the cell validation with lists don't fill down, the screenshots show the problem. I made sure to use the same cells in each case to show the differences

Comment: Validation rules aren't going to simply "fill down" unless they were explicitly selected when data validation rules were assigned or they they are in the middle of existing rows/columns when a new row/column is inserted between cells where data validation has already explicitly been defined.

Comment: That can't be true because the validation rules are filling down as long as it's not a list validation. Also, when I insert a new row to the bottom of the table all of the validation rules fill down.

Comment: I misspoke about inserting a new row directly adjacent to cells with a data validation rules. If you insert a row directly below cells that have data validation rules, the data validation rules will expand. However, if you just define a rule in A1 and don't insert a new row between A and B, then B1 will not have a data validation rule.

Comment: Have you tried clearing all cells below the table? What happens if you hit `TAB` when you're in the last row and last column of the table? I think the row banding issue is a clue that the table isn't expanding for some reason. That would explain why validation doesn't show up when adding a row at the end of the table.

Comment: The row banding was a formatting issue. I had the cells filled with white and that was overriding the table formatting, so I fixed that temporarily. I found a work around to make the data validation work. I entered the validation in the empty cells below the table and manually drug it down. So its there in the row for people to see when they need to add a row. It's not perfect but It works.